# Javascript flashing text longer on 1 colour

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a problem. I wish to flash (or blink) text from yellow to grey, but I would like the yellow text to remain displayed longer than the grey text.

The code that I have works for an equal duration for each color.

```
function flashtext(ele,col) {
var tmpColCheck = document.getElementById( ele ).style.color;

   if (tmpColCheck === 'grey') {
       document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = col;
   } else {
       document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = 'grey';
   }
 } 

setInterval(function() {
    flashtext('flashingtext','yellow');
}, 700 ); //set an interval timer up to repeat the function
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout`:

```
function flashtext(ele,col) {
    var tmpColCheck = document.getElementById( ele ).style.color,
        time;
    if (tmpColCheck === 'grey') {
        document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = col;
        time=1400;
    } else {
        document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = 'grey';
        time=700;
    }
    setTimeout(function(){flashtext('flashingtext','yellow')},time);
}
flashtext('flashingtext','yellow');
```

[**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/EfpEP/](http://jsfiddle.net/EfpEP/1/)

**Edit**:

But it can be improved a bit:

```
function flashtext(ele,col) {
    var style = document.getElementById(ele).style;
    (function main(){
        var cond=style.color === 'grey';
        style.color=cond?col:'grey';
        setTimeout(main,cond?1400:700);
    })();
}
flashtext('flashingtext','yellow');
```

[**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/EfpEP/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/EfpEP/3/)

Alnitak had the great idea of storing the color because the browser can change it to another syntax. But his code is calling `document.getElementById` each time. Then, taking his idea, I think the best way is:

```
function flashtext(ele,col) {
    var style = document.getElementById(ele).style,
        cond=style.color === 'grey';
    (function main(){
        cond=!cond;
        style.color=cond?col:'grey';
        setTimeout(main,cond?1400:700);
    })();
}
flashtext('flashingtext','yellow');
```

[**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/EfpEP/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/EfpEP/4/)

**Edit 2:**

But if you are going to use something like

```
flashtext('flashingtext','yellow');
flashtext('flashingtext2','blue');
...
```

you will end up freezing the browser.

Instead, you should use

```
function FlashText(){
    var arr=[],
        cond=false,
        started=false;
    this.add=function(el,col){
        if(typeof el==='string'){el=document.getElementById(el);}
        arr.push([el.style,col]);
    }
    this.start=function(){
        if(started){return;}
        started=true;
        main();
    }
    function main(){
        cond=!cond;        
        for(var i=0,l=arr.length;i<l;i++){
            arr[i][0].color=cond?arr[i][1]:'grey';
        }
        setTimeout(main,cond?1400:700);
    };
}
var flash=new FlashText();
flash.add('flashingtext','yellow');
flash.add('flashingtext2','blue');
flash.start();
```

You can also call passing an element by reference: `flash.add(document.getElementById('flashingtext'),'yellow')` (maybe you have a variable which contains an element which has no id).

But try not to add more elements after `flash.start()`. If you do that, the element will be black (or default color) until `main` is called (maybe 1.4 seconds).

[**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/EfpEP/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/EfpEP/6/)

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but some constructive criticism follows:  1.  You've got three different calls to `document.getElementBuyId()`.  2.  it will only flash an element with ID `flashingtext`.  3.  You can use local state to store the grey/not-grey, avoiding the need to read the style, which may have been converted to another syntax by the browser.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, I answered without modifing asker's code very much, but then I realized it and I edited my answer.

Comment: good point about repeated calls to `getElementById()` in my answer - I've updated it.  FWIW, I think my new one is still the best because I just use a boolean to store the state, not the colour itself ;-)  I've deliberately not optimised storing a pointer to the `style` object itself - that's just overkill.

Comment: @Alnitak I don't store the color either, `cond=style.color === 'grey'` is a boolean too. But why storing `style` is overkill but storing the element isn't?

Comment: None of these solutions work, but my if I return to my original code it still does as it should. Why would it work in jsfiddle and not in my project?

Comment: @SheedySheedySheedy Can you give us a link to your site updated with Alnitak's code or mine?

Comment: @Oriol I only have it on localhost xampp

Comment: @Oriol because calling DOM functions is expensive but accessing properties is (normally) cheap.

Comment: @Alnitak But `style` is a property, so it should be cheap to store it, shouldn't it? Why is it overkill?

Comment: @SheedySheedySheedy Try opening the console, maybe an error is thrown so the code isn't executed.

Comment: @Oriol I get this error: TypeError: document.getElementById(ele) is null

Comment: @SheedySheedySheedy That's because you call the function before loading `ele` to the DOM. Try calling the function inside onload event (`document.body.onload=function(){/* Code */}`) or placing the script just before `</body>`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, you mean?

```
function flashtext(id, col) {
    var grey = true,
        el = document.getElementById(id);
    (function f() {
        grey = !grey;
        el.style.color = grey ? 'grey' : col;
        setTimeout(f, grey ? 500 : 1000);
    })();
};
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/8LYG2/

This code uses the local variable `grey` to store the current state, rather than attempt to read it from the element.  This is both very efficient, and eliminates the risk that the browser might have converted the `.style.color` property into another format.

The inner closure is then responsible for toggling the state, changing the element's style, and then recursively queueing itself again with the appropriate timeout.

Comment: It's a good idea storing the color because the browser can change it to another syntax, I haven't thought that +1

Comment: I have tried this and the other poster's solution and they do not work. I used your code and called the function with the correct element id and yellow as parameters. No luck.

Comment: @SheedySheedySheedy have you remembered to put the code inside an `onload` handler.

Comment: @Alnitak No, I am sorry for my ignorance, but I am a novice with javascript.